# Read text values from table with same name in for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating online cart. In that i'm getting values through jquery/json GET from my spring/hibernate and it is running with no problems.  I've some bugs in adding them in js class now I just want to read each row's textbox's value by it's name.

for Eg:

`var product = $('[name="product"]').val();
 var vendor = $('[name="vendor"]').val();`

```
<table style="width: 90%; margin: 15px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="border-bottom: 2px solid gray;">
                        <th style="float: left; text-align: left !important" width="50%">Product
                            Details</th>
                        <th style="float: left; text-align: left !important" width="25%">Vendor</th>
                        <th style="float: left; text-align: left !important" width="20%">Quantity</th>
                        <th style="float: left; text-align: left !important" width="5%"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="tbdyProducts"
                    style="min-height: 300px; max-height: 300px; overflow: auto; display: block;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top: 15px; float: left; width: 350px"><span
                            id="product1" name="product">Xperia M Dual</span></td>
                        <td style="padding-top: 15px; float: left; width: 190px"><span
                            id="vendorname1" name="seller" style="height: 20px">sample
                                vendorname</span></td>
                        <td style="padding-top: 15px; float: left; width: 100px"><input
                            type="text" id="proqty1" name="proqty" size="5"
                            style="height: 20px; text-align: center" value=""></td>
                        <td align="right" valign="bottom" style="width: 55px"><span
                            id="deleteRow" onclick="ProductRemove(1)" class="deleteRow"
                            style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand">X</span><input type="hidden"
                            id="hsrate1" name="hsrate" value="250.50"></td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="padding-top: 15px; float: left; width: 350px"><span
                            id="product2" name="product">Mouse</span></td>
                        <td style="padding-top: 15px; float: left; width: 190px"><span
                            id="vendorname2" name="seller" style="height: 20px">a valid
                                company or vendor name</span></td>
                        <td style="padding-top: 15px; float: left; width: 100px"><input
                            type="text" id="proqty2" name="proqty" size="5"
                            style="height: 20px; text-align: center" value=""></td>
                        <td align="right" valign="bottom" style="width: 55px"><span
                            id="deleteRow" onclick="ProductRemove(2)" class="deleteRow"
                            style="cursor: pointer; cursor: hand">X</span><input type="hidden"
                            id="hsrate2" name="hsrate" value="3.00"></td>
                    </tr>


                    <tr id="productSearch" style="display: none;">
                        <td style="padding-top: 15px; float: left; width: 350px"><span
                            role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible">1
                                result is available, use up and down arrow keys to navigate.</span><input
                            type="text" id="productfinder" size="40" style="height: 20px"
                            autocomplete="off" placeholder="Product Name or Code"
                            class="ui-autocomplete-input"></td>
                        <td style="padding-top: 15px; float: left; width: 190px"><span
                            id="vendorname" style="height: 20px"> </span></td>
                        <td style="padding-top: 15px; float: left; width: 100px"><input
                            type="text" size="5" id="productnos"
                            style="height: 20px; text-align: center"></td>
                        <td align="right" valign="bottom" style="width: 55px"><span>X</span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

I tried like this but it didn't work:

```
for(i=0; i< $('[name="product"]').length; i++){
    var product = $(this).find('[name="product"]').val();
    alert(product);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method for this:

```
var product = $('[name="product"]').eq(i).val();
alert(product);
```

but I would suggest you to use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method

```
$( '[name="product"]' ).each( function() {
  var product = $( this ).val();
  console.log( product );
});
```

---

Update:

If you want to read there vendor also, you can modify `each` to accept `index`:

```
$( '[name="product"]' ).each( function( index ) {
  var product = $( this ).val();
  var vendor = $( '[name="product"]' ).eq( index ).val();
  console.log( product );
  console.log( vendor );
});
```

Comment: that's looking good but if i use each i've to read vendor name as well in same row

Comment: Yeah It's worked. I just used your Updated code thanks... Answer accepting denying 1 min is remining

Answer (score 1):

Note that your HTML is invalid (in various ways): Table cell elements don't have `name` or `value` attributes. If you want to put arbitrary information in attributes, use `data-*` attributes instead. (You're also using the same `id` on more than one element; `id` values **must** be unique on the page.)

So two issues:

1. You're using `find` to look *within* the elements, but in fact you want the information from the element you're already looking at
2. You're using `val`, but the elements in question aren't form fields. It *might* work, but if so, it's undocumented.

The simple, reliable thing is to use [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each) and [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr):

```
$('[name="product"]').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("value"));
});
```

If instead of alerting you want an array of the values, [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map) and [`get`](http://api.jquery.com/get):

```
var values = $('[name="product"]').map(function() {
    return $(this).attr("value");
}).get();
```

But again, if you want to put arbitrary attrs on, you'll want to use `data-name` and `data-value` instead.

Comment: Thank you sir I just executed antyrat's code worked as expected. your code too seems the same anyway thanks for sharing ur time

Comment: @Venkat: Using `val` on elements that aren't form fields, as in that other answer, is a bad idea; there's no guarantee at all it'll work correctly cross-browser.